# URL markup validation error

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, w3c-validation

I've added following code for the URL:

```
<a href='http://facebook.com/share.php?u="<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>"&amp;t="<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>"' target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i><?php _e('Facebook', 'domain'); ?></a>
```

It generates this output:

```
<a href='http://facebook.com/share.php?u="http://example.com/abc/"&amp;t="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"' target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
```

But I get error in the validation:

> Bad value
>   http://facebook.com/share.php?u="http://example.com/abc/"&t="Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet" for attribute href on element a: **Illegal
>   character in query: not a URL code point**.

How can I fix this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `"` in url. Your link element format should be like;

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com?a=john" target="_blank">User</a>
```

You can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) for html link format, and you can use this;

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>&amp;t=<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i><?php _e('Facebook', 'domain'); ?></a>
```

Comment: I have already tried that without "", and it does not help at all.

Comment: @user1117313 any error? or can you see link generated in the page source code?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out already. There were spaces in the title which was part of the URL. So I managed to fix it.